# (NSError *__strong *)magic

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

Without any preamble I want to show you problem I have in my program, I commented out steps and my thoughts for that steps. (I didn't include `@interface` part for shortness, it has same method with the same signature as in `@implementation`)

```
@implementation Dummy

- (int)testing:(NSError *__strong *)error 
{
    *error = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"hello" code:42 userInfo:nil]; 
    // 3. retain count = 1

    // 4. because of ARC 'error' object was released for this time 
    // (assembly output is my proof) object is deallocated
    // retain count = 0

    return 0;
}

@end

int main()
{
    NSError *e = nil; // 1. retain count = 0 (obviously)
    Dummy *dummy = [[Dummy alloc] init];

    [dummy testing:&e]; // 2. passing reference to an error object

    // 'e' for this time has to be just a trash, or nil maybe, 
    // but next log gives me correct output: 
    NSLog(@"%@ %li", [e domain], [e code]); // 'hello 42'

    return 0;
}
```

How does an error object exist after it death? I understand that using `NSError *__autoreleasing *` will be right way to go, and situation will be trivial in that case, but how compiler reasoning for this code, where is my mistake in judgements?

It's a bit an artificial question, but I can't throw out this situation from my head, I think I'm loosing something.

Here is part of disassembly for `-[Dummy testing:]`

```
callq  0x100000e8c <dyld_stub_objc_msgSend>
mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rcx
mov    (%rcx),%rdx
mov    %rax,(%rcx)
mov    %rdx,%rdi
callq  0x100000e92 <dyld_stub_objc_release>
mov    -0x24(%rbp),%eax
add    $0x40,%rsp
pop    %rbp
retq
```

If I understood correctly, there is only one object in this method, and it's clearly released, not autoreleased or something else.

Comment: BTW, under ARC, all object stack variables are initialized to nil, so you don't need to say `= nil` in your declaration of `NSError *e`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your confused about what's getting released. I just checked the assembly output, and there is a call to `objc_release()`, though I'm not familiar enough with x86 assembly to actually trace precisely what's going on. However, I *do* know that the code here is expected to emit something of the equivalent of:

```
NSError *temp = [[NSError alloc] initWithDomain:@"hello" code:42 userInfo:nil];
[*error release];
*error = [temp retain];
[temp release];
```

and of course the optimizer will shrink that to

```
NSError *temp = ...
[*error release];
*error = temp;
```

So I think you're seeing the call to `objc_release()` and thinking that your newly-allocated error is being released. It's not. The previous value of `*error` is being released before the newly-allocated error is placed in that location.

Comment: It is interesting, where can I read about such behavior of the compiler? I thought if object given by reference is strong, it is retained (in this example just retaining nil), and then released (which released actual object after alloc).

Comment: @goodfella: Not quite sure what you mean. Under ARC, when writing to a `__strong` location, the previous value at that location is released and the new value is retained. That produces the code snippet you see in my answer. Now, if the optimizer can prove that pairs of retains/releases are unnecessary it can remove them, which leads to my slightly shorter code snippet. Anyway, in this case, the alloc'd error won't get released inside `-testing:` because its storage location isn't going out of scope.

Comment: I confused myself with object ownership policy and "return by reference" situation just could not assembly them together, thank you for clarification.